# Исправление "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'" при помощи информации из дерева зависимостей

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

Работаю в Eclipse и изучаю Spring по официальным гайдам (конкретнее - [вот этот](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/), без какой либо отсебятины на текущий момент) и получаю ошибку

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Полный лог из консоли после появления ошибки:

```html
Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
 at hello.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
 ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
 ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Насколько я понимаю, после изучения похожих вопросов, проблема тут в зависимостях. Проверил дерево зависимостей и понял, что я не понимаю, как его прочесть и каких зависимостей мне не хватает.
1. Дерево зависимостей:

```html
[INFO] org.springframework:gs-mysql-data:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:8.0.15:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO]    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO]    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.10:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
```

2. pom.xml и настройки

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>gs-mysql-data</artifactId>
 <version>0.1.0</version>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

 
  <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

```html
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

3. Класс Application (единственный класс, на который в консоли есть ссылки, ругается на 10 строчку)

```html
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

4. Класс User

```html
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }


}
```

5. Класс реопзитория

```html
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import hello.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

6. Класс контроллера

```html
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import hello.User;
import hello.UserRepository;

@Controller    // This means that this class is a Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") // This means URL's start with /demo (after Application path)
public class MainController {
 @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
            // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
 private UserRepository userRepository;

 @GetMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY GET Requests
 public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
   , @RequestParam String email) {
  // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
  // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

  User n = new User();
  n.setName(name);
  n.setEmail(email);
  userRepository.save(n);
  return "Saved";
 }

 @GetMapping(path="/all")
 public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
  // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
  return userRepository.findAll();
 }
}
```

Собственно вопрос - как правильно читать это дерево? Как мне узнать, какие параметры необходимо вписать в описание новой заивисимости?

Comment: `entityManagerFactory` - откуда это, там же в коде нет такого. Добавьте полные свои данные, контроллер, entity, репозитория, что вы используете

Comment: С зависимостями у вас всё в порядке, смотреть нужно в лог приложения и читать его полностью. Приложение не может создать `entityManagerFactory` - нужно читать стектрейс ошибки, чтобы понять, почему. Например, у вас может быть не поднята БД или неправильный логин/пароль для БД или ещё что-нибудь.

Comment: @fori1ton спасибо, попробую разобраться.

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov добавил.

Comment: кажется в IDEA вы забыли отметить что ваша папка `resources` как Resources ROOT

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski http://prntscr.com/n2o9gr есть такое?

Comment: хотя, возможно дело не в этом, сейчас попробую ваш пример у себя запустить

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov у меня другая структура папок, я не стал изменять ничего из примера и выглядит это вот так: структура папок https://prnt.sc/n2oef2 расположение файлов https://prnt.sc/n2oexb

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski так в этом и проблема, должно быть `src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov к сожалению, на ошибку это никак не влияет (уже попробовал, всё осталось без изменений).

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski это ошибки при подключение к базе данных, дал ответ, попробуйте

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov да, вы абсолютно правы! Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @SergeiZhilinski своё время сам с этим настрадался))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При подключение к базе данных **MySQL**, нужно так же использовать параметры

- serverTimezone
- useSSL

Ваш код в `src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
```

Нужно исправить на

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?serverTimezone=Asia/Tashkent&useSSL=false
```