# Ошибка Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory - nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Учу Java Spring / REST Hateoas и с первыми учебными проектами всё было неплохо, но с новым случилась беда, и всё время на запуске выдаёт ошибку. Не могу понять, в чём причина - вроде всё делаю так же, как в рабочих проектах.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Гуглил и проверял здесь на сайте, но не нашёл ничего именно с NullPointerException, а стек для меня в этом случае непонятен, чтобы разобраться, что конкретно вызывает ошибку.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.example.shoptest.ShoptestApplication.main(ShoptestApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1672) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

на всякий случай прилагаю pom файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>shoptest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shoptest</name>
    <description>Shop Test for my project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Мда, а минусят тут за что?) Что не так в вопросе?

Comment: Основная ошибка это `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'` а null это как следствие

Comment: хех, ну от этого не легче) что там за entityManagerFactory... на стеке уже в других темах советовали и всякие зависимости добавлять, и порты менять - у меня ничего из этого не работает

Comment: посмотри это решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058001/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-defined-in-class-path-resou

Comment: ещё у чувака похожая проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961110/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: спасибо, но я уже все похожие вопросы проверил, ни одно решение не работает.

Comment: а такое? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864967/spring-boot-database-error-datasource-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-or

Comment: может ему не хватает драйвера для работы с базой?)

Comment: да нет, с базой всё ок должно быть, это ж H2, которая на лету создаётся, на разок) к реальной я даже не подключаюсь. В прошлом проекте для H2 хватало только dependency в поме и даже пустого properties (туториал от самого спринга)

Comment: я тут добрался до другого исключения UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name, попробую с ним разобраться... хоть более специфичная инфа

Comment: слушай, если есть github с этим проектом, то прикрепи к вопросу, может проще будет так разобраться, когда имеешь сам проект на руках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я и думал, причиной оказалась весьма простая ошибка, которую было сложно найти из-за неинформативности ошибки.

В одной из сущностей (Entity) составной первичный ключ - он у меня выделен в отдельный класс, который @Embeddable. И вот в нём в отношениях @ManyToOne поля были с типом Long, а не с типом классов родительских объектов.

То есть было так:

```
public class OrderItemPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
    private **Long** orderId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private **Long** productId;
```

А должно быть так:

```
public class OrderItemPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
    private **Order** orderId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private **Product** productId;
```

То есть "ссылаться" надо не на поле в родительской сущности, а на всю сущность.

Может, для кого-то это очевидно, но я как-то пропустил этот момент и никак не мог нащупать, где же ошибка)